# Python - Find sequence of same characters

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use regex to match sequences of one or more instances of the same characters in a string.

Example :

```
string = "55544355"
# The regex should retrieve sequences "555", "44", "3", "55"
```

Can I have a few tips?

Comment: You can use [`((\d)\2*)`](https://regex101.com/r/lI0fF7/1)

Comment: No need for the enclosing parenthesis though, so `(\d)\1*` would work as well. No mention about numbers either, so maybe more `(.)\1*`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) and the `((.)\2*)` regular expression:

```
>>> [item[0] for item in re.findall(r"((.)\2*)", string)]
['555', '44', '3', '55']
```

the key part is inside the outer capturing group - `(.)\2*`. Here we capture a single character via `(.)` then reference this character by the group number: `\2`. The group number is 2 because we have an outer capturing group with number 1. `*` means 0 or more times.

You could've also solved it with a single capturing group and [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
>>> [item.group(0) for item in re.finditer(r"(.)\1*", string)]
['555', '44', '3', '55']
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7):

You can do this easily without regex using [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> s = '55544355'
>>> [''.join(g) for _, g in groupby(s)]
['555', '44', '3', '55']
```

Comment: This feels like a cleaner solution than the answer. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the best option here, but for the sake of variety, how about this logic:

```
>>> def f(s):
        l = []
        c = s[0]
        for x in s:
            if x in c:
                c += x
                continue
            l.append(c)
            c = x
        l.append(c)
        return l

>>> f('55544355')
['555', '44', '3', '55']
>>> f('123444555678999001')
['1', '2', '3', '444', '555', '6', '7', '8', '999', '00', '1']
```

Comment: Thanks for the approach, but this time I was interested in using Regex.