# How can I check the length of consecutive characters in a list in python?

Tags: python, count, unique

Basically say I have a list in python

```
lst = [6, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1]
```

the program should return 4 because the number '1' is displayed 4 times in a consecutive manner. Btw the number 6 also displays in a consecutive manner but the program should get the number that shows up the most while being consecutive

more examples:

```
[6, 4, 4, 4, 1, 1, 7]
```

should output 3 because '4' is consecutive 3 times

I've been stuck on this problem for a while now, any advice??

Comment: `itertools.groupby`

Answer (score 2):

[`groupby()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) will give you individual groups of the same value by default:

```
> [list(g) for k, g in groupby(lst)] 
[[6, 6], [7], [1, 1, 1, 1], [4], [1]]
```

You can pass that to `max()` with a key of `len` to get the longest one:

```
> from itertools import group-by
> lst = [6, 6, 7, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 1]
> max((list(g) for k, g in groupby(lst)), key=len)
[1, 1, 1, 1]
```

That's the longest grouping, from which you can get the length. Alternatively you can just build a list of lengths and call `max` without the key:

```
max(len(list(g)) for k, g in groupby(lst))
```

Answer (score 0):

Two different questions may help.

First to transform the text into list you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8266559/11261546) answer.

Once you have your list, you need to count consecutive values, it was asked and solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58578557/11261546).